# Slowing down a synchronous AC motor

Tags: ac-motor

I'd like to slow down the little AC motor, which drives the mechanical controls on my washing machine (yes it's ancient but it works just fine). The wash cycle is a bit short, and I'd like to make it longer.

So, short of building a variable frequency inverter, I thought maybe I can slow down the motor by building a circuit which lets through only some AC cycles, something like this:
[image: 50% speed]

50% speed

Of course the speed would oscillate up and down at a rate of 25Hz. Would that be a problem for the motor?

Thanks!

Comment: No, won't work. It would make more sense to simply interrupt the power to the timer motor for the amount of time by which you want to lengthen the wash cycle.

Comment: i think something like that could work, but i would block it into say 5 complete waves, then a period of silence, then 5 more waves etc, to make sure the motor worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of modulating the mains is sound, but a cycle or two at a time is probably not as the motor will constantly be in an ill-defined startup regime, rather than half speed.

If this is a typical slow geared controller, with relatively coarse event scheduling, you should consider longer duration on-off action, say every 5s. This is also easier to arrange with a simple SSR driven by a 0.1Hz square wave.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, thanks. It would appear I have to go with a mechanical relay though. The datasheets of the SSRs I had a look at specify a minimum load current of around 20mA. I don't know the exact power rating of the motor but I suspect the current draw is less than 20mA.